# new Text(counter.toString()) display doesn't update with counter increment in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a food cart app using `flutter`. But, I got stuck in displaying the counter value when incremented or decremented at the trailing of `Listtile`.

Whenever a new item is added to cart, the counter gets incremented but the app doesn't display the current counter value.

Here is the following code. I have placed comments where the problem is being faced.Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ifhe_canteen/StudentCart.dart';
class StudentHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );//MaterialApp
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  HomePage1 createState() => new HomePage1();
  }
class HomePage1 extends State<HomePage>{
  int selectedPage=0;
  final pageOptions=[
    Text('Messages'),
    Text('Cart'),
    Text('Profile'),

  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var Listview=ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
        )
      ],
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Categories'),
      ),
      body:new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new StuffInTiles(listOfTiles[index]);
          },
          itemCount: listOfTiles.length,
        ),
      ),//body: pageOptions[selectedPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: selectedPage,
        onTap: (int index){
          setState(() {
            selectedPage=index;
          });
        },// this will be set when a newx  tab is tapped
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
            title: new Text('Cart'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('Profile'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyTile myTile;
  StuffInTiles(this.myTile);
  int _itemCount;
  String item;
  void _removeproduct(){
    _itemCount--;
    print(_itemCount);
  }
  int _addproduct(){
    _itemCount++;
    print(_itemCount);
    item=_itemCount.toString();
    print(item);
    return _itemCount;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(myTile);
  }

  Widget _buildTiles  (MyTile t) {
    if (t.children.isEmpty)
      {
        return new ListTile(
          dense: true,
          enabled: true,
          isThreeLine: false,
          title: new Text(t.title),
          trailing:new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              new  IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove),onPressed:()=>_removeproduct()),
              new Text(_itemCount.toString()),//here, the incremented value  is not displayed
              new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add),onPressed:()=>_addproduct()),//here the function is called
            ],
          ),
          onTap:()=>print("here cart value will be incremented"),
        );
      }
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<MyTile>(t),
      title: new Text(t.title),
      children: t.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTile {
  String title;
  List<MyTile> children;
  MyTile(this.title, [this.children = const <MyTile>[]]);
}

List<MyTile> listOfTiles = <MyTile>[
  new MyTile(
    'Mess 1',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile(
        'Maggie',
        <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Veg Cheese Maggie'),
          new MyTile('Plain Maggie'),
          new MyTile('Chicken Maggie'),
        ],
      ),//Maggie
      new MyTile(
          'Paratha',
          <MyTile>[
            new MyTile('Veg Paratha'),
            new MyTile('Veg Butter Paratha'),
            new MyTile('Chicken Paratha'),
            new MyTile('Chicken Butter Paratha'),
          ],
      ),//Paratha
    ],
  ),
  new MyTile(
    'Mess 2',
    <MyTile>[
      new MyTile(
        'Maggie',
        <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Veg Cheese Maggie'),
          new MyTile('Plain Maggie'),
          new MyTile('Chicken Maggie'),
        ],
      ),//Maggie
      new MyTile(
        'Paratha',
        <MyTile>[
          new MyTile('Veg Paratha'),
          new MyTile('Veg Butter Paratha'),
          new MyTile('Chicken Paratha'),
          new MyTile('Chicken Butter Paratha'),
        ],
      ),//Paratha
    ],
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setState` whenever you update a variable on your code, and want to see that change reflected on the screen. Note that it only works in StatefulWidgets, which means that if you need that, you need a StatefulWidget (as you already do). The setState method will refresh the screen and the viewed value will change.

Edit your `_addproduct` and `_removeproduct` function to have a setState on the _itemCounter variable:

```
void _removeproduct(){
  setState((){
    _itemCount--;
  });
}
int _addproduct(){
  setState((){
    _itemCount++;
  });
}
```

I suggest you [read some articles](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) on how to use states in Flutter. Best regards.